# Error converting bytecode to dex whilte running in real device

Tags: android, runtime-error

I updated kolin version 1.1.4-2 and then i start running my project in real device but it's showing this error ->

[image: Error message]

Module:app build.gradle file i add last time targetCompatibility in dependency but it's not work at all. whenever i run in my device it's showing above error->

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.projectname"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Project build.gradle file ->

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly tells you to change the `target` and `source` compatibilities to `1.7` in a library's sub-module. Why can't just change that?

I think it probably asks you to change
this:

```
compileKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
compileTestKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
}
```

to this:

```
compileKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.7"
}
}
compileTestKotlin {
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.7"
}
}
```